Connection between Heat and Laplace's equation
According to Evans, "a guiding principle (in the study of heat equation) is that any assertion about harmonic functions yields an analogous (but more complicated) statement about solutions of the heat equation. Accordingly, our development (for the heat equation) will largely parallel the corresponding theory for Laplace's equation".
I was wondering why that is true and why there is a connection between those two equations $$
\partial_tu-\Delta u=0 \qquad \hbox{and}\qquad \Delta u=0
$$
and not, for example, with the wave equation $u_{tt}-\Delta u=0$. Could anyone explain why Heat and Laplace solutions should share properties? My main issue is that every time I try to come up with an explanation, then I can't explain why that works for the heat and Laplace's equations but not for the wave equation (which obviously does not share many properties with the other two, right?).

One physical reason is that transfer of heat typically stops after some time (or approach equilibrium) while undamped waves usually keeps on moving forever. Thus solutions to the heat equation usually approach a steady-state solution ($u_t = 0$) which are given by the Laplace equation $\nabla^2 u = 0$, but this rarely happens for solutions to the wave-equation.

The main reason we are studying these equations is precisely because they model physical systems and physical reasoning do underlie many mathematical tools we use to study them (for example energy functionals) so yes I would say its a big advantage to know some basic physics to have some intuition when studying them. That said I'm sure its possible to deduce these things just from studying the PDE itself. For example one key property one can show is that both Laplace and Heat satisfy a "maximum principle" while Wave does not.

Maybe this question is useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214533/distinguishing-between-laplaces-equation-and-heat-equation

About the difference between heat and wave equations, the heat equation damps high frequencies exponentially (see separation of variables for a simple example), so it increases regularity. The wave equation simply oscillates high frequencies faster so any lack of regularity in a initial condition never goes away, even if the equilibrium state is a harmonic function
